# Regex question- string must appear in a specific way or not at all

Tags: regex

i need help with a REGEX expression (for analytics).
not sure how to handle the requirements.

Here's an example of a URL:

```
/a.html?ref=aa&project=11&utm=bb
```

This URL would have `&project=XX` in the middle but it is possible that `&project` won't be there at all..

Requirements:

1. I want the regex to be positive only for specific project=XX (for example only when XX equals 11 or 12 or 13) but negative for all other values (project=22).
2. The parameter before it (`?ref` in the example below) is mandatory
3. Any parameter afterwards (`&utm`) is optional

For example:

- fine: /a.html?ref=aa&project=11&utm=bb
- fine: /a.html?ref=aa&utm=bb
- not fine: /a.html?ref=aa&project=22&utm=bb

How do I approach this?

I tried this it kinda works (but only without additional utm params):

```
\/a.html\?ref\=aa(\&project\=(11|12|13))?$
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work when using the utm parameter:

```
\/a.html\?ref\=aa(\&project\=(11|12|13))?(\&utm\=.*)?$
```

Thanks
Itay

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what platform you're using, but you'll need to escape your forward slashes and question marks if you want them to match literal characters on most platforms:

`\/a.html\?ref=aa(&project=(11|12|13))?(&utm=.*)?$`

You might also want to minimize your capture in the `utm` block in case other things come after it that you don't want:

`\/a.html\?ref=aa(&project=(11|12|13))?(&utm=.*?)?$`

Answer (score 0):

You could use character class `[123]` to match either 1,2 or 3 with a single optional group, and note to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
\/a\.html\?ref=aa(&project=1[123])?&utm=.*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `\/a\.html` match `/a.html`
- `\?ref=aa` Match `?ref=aa`
- `(` Capture group

  - `&project=1[123]` Match &project=1 and then either 1,2 or 3
- `)?` Close the non capture group to make it optional
- `&utm=.*$` Match &utm= followed by the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DWxucZ/1)